# C# web browser click on text

Tags: c#, onclick, click, browser

I want to click the text "Check All" on website using web browser method. I don't get any idea how to do it.
This is HTML code of the website:

```
<a onclick="checkAll(document.myform.list)" href="#">Check all</a>
<a onclick="uncheckAll(document.myform.list)" href="#">Uncheck all</a>
<input type="hidden" value="t2ah9m" name="check">
```

My code to click on it:

```
webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("check")[0].SetAttribute("Value", "Click");
```

But failed..

this is the sript:

```
function checkAll(field)
{   for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)  field[i].checked = true ;   }

function uncheckAll(field)
{for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) field[i].checked = false;   }
```

Comment: What is your javascript click function?

Comment: I add the script function.

Comment: Your missing `{ }` around your `field[i].checked = true\false;` statements for a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to select all the input types `checkbox`

e.g.:
Your form

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>
```

Your links

```
<a id="checkAll" href="#">Check all</a>
<a id="uncheckAll" href="#">Uncheck all</a>
```

Your javascript

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
    $('type').find('checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});

$("#uncheckAll").click(function() {
    $('type').find('checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to do it with that, because it's way too complex and the jquery library solves a lot of trouble for you. Either that or you try it yourself, I'm not your coder. This is not the place to get your homework done...